# Does the first 'matplotlibrc' file encountered completely determine matplotlib's configuration

Tags: configuration, matplotlib

The matbpotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib) describes the order in which "matplotlib looks for `matplotlibrc`" files, but it is unclear whether the first `matplotlibrc` file encountered completely determines the `rc` settings, or whether only those values set in a given file are used.

Does the first `matplotlibrc` file encountered completely determine matplotlib's configuration, or are settings absent from a given file sought in files later in the search order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it only reads the first file it hits.  The rest of the values are filled in from the defaults.  The relevant functions are in [`__init__.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py).

There is a [PR](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2236) (which will hopefully be merged to master soon) which allows you to load 'style sheet' like rcparam files to set just some of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I look forward to get getting merged.